# Network monitor for taskbar in Windows

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, bandwidth, network-monitoring

I am interested in monitoring my bandwidth via an icon in the taskbar of my windows 7 machine.  I recently found [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) which provides exactly the feature I want, but with RAM, CPU, GPU, and disk I/O. My taskbar currently looks like

[image: Taskbar contents RAM CPU GPU IO etc]

and I would simply like to add another box there for network activity. Since I am using the program only passively, I would like it it be lightweight if possible. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who are wondering, I ended up using [bitmeter](http://bitmeter-ii.en.softonic.com/).

Answer (score 2):

NetWorx is a good bandwidth monitoring app: http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/

Comment: The program LOOKS really good, but it seems to be giving me completely bogus information. It says I'm downloading at 2 Gbit/s when in reality I am idle on a network capped at 54Mbit/s. It also seems to think that I've downloaded 900GB since install (definitely not).

Comment: You need to configure Networx to only measure data over certain connections. LAN traffic also counts as traffic to Networx.

Comment: NetWorx is no longer a freeware , here is a link to last free version => https://filehippo.com/download_softperfect-networx/71287/